# How to find selected row using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table and a button to get the selected row:

```
<table id="mytable" class="table-striped">
    <tbody>
        <tr id="1"><td>Test1</td></tr>
        <tr id="2"><td>Test2</td></tr>
        <tr id="3"><td>Test3</td></tr>
        <tr id="4"><td>Test4</td></tr>
        <tr id="5"><td>Test5</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button id="btn">Get Selected Row</button>
```

When I clicked the row I set the background color into red.

```
$('#mytable').on('click', 'tbody tr', function (event) {
    $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');
});

function getRow() {
    $('table > tbody > tr').find('background-color: red');
}

$('#btn').click(function (e) {
    var selrow = getRow();
    console.log(selrow);
    if (selrow != undefined)
        alert(selrow.attr('id'));
    else
        alert('undefined');
});
```

The question is how to get the selected row (where background color is red) using jquery, when I clicked the button?

Here is what I've done: http://jsfiddle.net/xu2AH/865/

Comment: you are adding a class `highlight` from there you can 
get it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can match any rows that have the `.highlight` class with `tr.highlight`.

If you want the jQuery object (if a match is found) you'll need to return it within your `getRow()` function:

```
function getRow() {
    return $('table > tbody > tr.highlight');
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xu2AH/867/)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're adding `.higlight` class into clicked rows, then find it using those class :

```
function getRow() {
  // here you need to return the value
  // to be available when function was called
  return $('table > tbody').find('.highlight');
}

$('#btn').click(function (e) {
  var selrow = getRow();
  // index of selected row
  alert('Index is :' +selrow.index());
  // text of selected row
  alert('My text is :' +selrow.text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
$(".table-striped > tbody > tr").each(function()
    if ($(this).hasClass("highlight"))
        console.log($(this).attr("id"));
);
```

This way it will print on the lçog the id of the selected row